# adding path of samtools

Tags: path

I have installed samtools under my folder of choice. Also there is another different version of samtools present in `/usr/local/bin/samtools` I installed under my choice of folder latest version of samtools.

When I use `which samtools` I get

```
/usr/local/bin/samtools
```

How can I permanently use only that release of samtools which I have installed?
Do I need to delete /usr/local/bin/samtools and then use
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/my/folder

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to delete `/usr/local/bin/samtools`.  If you add `/path/to/your/folder` so that it precedes `/usr/local/bin/samtools`, it will take precedence and will show up when issuing the `which samtools` command.

```
export PATH=/path/to/your/folder:$PATH
```

This will preserve the original `samtools` which can still be called by absolute path, if necessary.

Comment: @user3138373 If this answer solved your problem, please indicate that by [marking it as accepted](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check mark next to it.